# c# Forward Values to Other Forms Question

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox

Form : The part where the employee name and department name are selected in the grid view of `frm_user_cd` to move the value to the combobox of form : `frm_gjmjs0`.
Running the code below will cause problems such as `System.NullReferenceException`.

I wish I could give the value of the grid view of `frm_user_cd` directly to the combobox of `frm_gjmjs0`. But I didn't know how to import the value into the text box of `frm_user_cd` and pass it back to the combobox of `frm_gjmjs0` and create a global variable of string type

```
user = dgv_user.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

The same error occurs when a variable is declared to and passed to `frm_gjs0.Cbx_user_cd`.

```
private void dgv_user_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    tbx_emp.Text = dgv_user.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    tbx_dept.Text = dgv_user.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}

private void btn_user_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        frm_gjmjs0.cbx_user_cd.Text = tbx_emp.Text;
        frm_gjmjs0.cbx_dept_cd.Text = tbx_dept.Text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this refers to Windows Forms, please add the "winforms" tag

Comment: @KlausGütter  Srry.. add it :)

Comment: @MathewHD uhmm...I didn't understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a property to access the `cbx_user_cd` in `frm_gjmjs0`.

```
public ComboBox CBXUser
{
    get { return cbx_user_cd; }
    set { value = cbx_user_cd; }
}
```

Then get the opened `frm_gjmjs0` instance via [`Application.OpenForms Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1).

```
private void buttoninfrm_user_cd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get frm_gjmjs0 instance
    frm_gjmjs0 form = (frm_gjmjs0)Application.OpenForms["frm_gjmjs0"];
    // modify cbx_user_cd text
    form.CBXUser.Text = "123";
}
```

You can set `cbx_dept_cd` in the same way.